# MySQLI, need to merge empty values with same ID into 1 row, and add to same row also if multiple inputs

Tags: select, join, mysqli, group-by, group-concat

I have a hard time figuring this one out. And i apologize if the answer is out there, i have searched through all of stackoverflow.

I have an order system, where i order by tableID, and continue to make rows in my Database if someone orders stuff. My problem is getting my data out on 1 row, in this example the table ID, so all the ordered stuff, shows on 1 line only.

I have 3 tables, Food, Drink, Dessert, all with a foreign key in my OrderTable.

```
id  fk_tableid  fk_drinkId   fk_foodId    fk_dessId    amount
1   5           2            0            0            2                             
2   5           0            1            0            1                              
3   5           0            2            0            1             
4   5           0            0            2            2                        
11  8           1            0            0            2            
21  1           1            0            0            5    
22  1           0            1            0            9
23  1           0            0            1            2
```

By a normal select, with left joins, i can get the data out on multiple rows, like this where i get those with tableId 5 and showing the name of the ordered consumable also:

```
id  fk_tableId   fk_drinkId     fk_foodId  fk_dessId    amount  foodName    drinkName   dessertName
1   5            2              0          0            2       NULL        Sodavand    NULL
2   5            0              1          0            1       Lasagne     NULL        NULL
3   5            0              2          0            1       Pizza       NULL        NULL
4   5            0              0          2            2       NULL        NULL        Softice
```

I tried using group_concat also, which put data on 1 line, but it seems to put everything on 1 line, not just grouped by tableId.

How i want it to be is something like this (the 2x Lasagne for example, is just how i want it to look at the site, but maybe i need to use 1xLasagne twice instead. It would just look messy with 1x Beer 10 times.):

```
fk_tableId   fk_drinkId    fk_foodId    fk_dessId   foodName          drinkName          dessertName         fulllPrice
5            2,2         1,2            2,2         Pizza,Lasagne     2xSodavand         2xSoftice           195
```

I am aware my question might be wrongly formatted, but i also have a hard time 100% knowing what to google and search for here. I have tried for 2 days, and even asked my teacher who could not do it, he was doing something with **CASES and sum()**, but it did not work out either.

Any help will be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

Added SQL Query:

```
 SELECT 
        menukort_ordre.id,
       fk_tableId, 
       fk_drinkId,
       fk_foodId, 
       fk_dessId, 
       amount,
       menukort_food.name AS foodName,
       menukort_drink.name AS drinkName,
       menukort_dessert.name AS dessertName
       FROM menukort_ordre
       LEFT Join menukort_drink
       ON (menukort_ordre.fk_drinkId = menukort_drink.id)
       LEFT Join menukort_food
       ON (menukort_ordre.fk_foodId = menukort_food.id)
       LEFT Join menukort_dessert
       ON (menukort_ordre.fk_dessId = menukort_dessert.id)
       WHERE fk_tableid = fk_tableid
```

With GROUP_CONCAT i tried to do this instead, which put it on 1 row, but due to my WHERE, i get all data on 1 row.

```
   GROUP_CONCAT(menukort_food.name ) AS foodName,
                         GROUP_CONCAT(menukort_drink.name) AS drinkName,
                         GROUP_CONCAT(menukort_dessert.name) AS dessertName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

First off I changed your database design since there was no need for 3 tables like that unless you really wanted them to be separated as such.  I understand wanting to separate data, but there are times to do so and times not to do it.  I understand since my personal database project has me breaking everything up.  So the below solution will be based off of my design which is as follows.

### Category

Code or ID  (PK)
Category

This table will be a lookup table just to make sure drink and food and desert is spelled correctly.  Frankly you don't need it unless you need that information specific and want it to be correct.

Next will be the table that stores the drinks, deserts, and food

### Items

ID serial
Category
Name
Price

and final the order table that will keep track of the orders

### Order

BillID
TableNum
ItemNum (fk)
ID (PK)

This way you can keep track of which table the food goes to and each check or bill.  Your design was fine if you wanted to find out how much each table made in a day, but I'm assuming like an actual restaurant you would want to know for each bill.  With this you can have multiple orders of a coke or whatever at the same table on the same bill.

Now on to the solution.

This doesn't have the count, but could work on it if you really need it, but frankly I think it is pointless to have a count unless you are going to ungroup the results and have something like this:

tableNum BillNum ItemNum ItemName
1 1 1 Coke
1 1 2 Steak
1 1 3 Pasta
1 1 1 Coke

then you could end up with something like this

tableNum BillNum ItemNum ItemName TimesBy
1 1 1 Coke 2
1 1 2 Steak 1
1 1 3 Pasta 1

The SQL CODE below will give you what you need I believe.  I'm using my version of the database and I think you should too just because it is easier and there is no point to having 3 tables for each thing.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (
select BillID, tablenum,ItemNum,Items.name,Items.price
from Orders, Items
where Orders.ItemNum=Items.id
);

create TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table3 AS (
select SUM(price) as total, BillID
from table2
group by BillID
);

select table3.BillID, TableNum, GROUP_CONCAT(ItemNum order by ItemNum ASC) as ItemNum, GROUP_CONCAT(name order by name ASC) as Item, GROUP_CONCAT(price order by name asc) as   ItemPrice, total
from table2, table3
where table2.BillID=table3.BillID
group by BillID;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table3;
```

A few other solutions would be to look into using something like php (programming) to help with this or a stored procedure.

If you need an explanation just ask.  Also I'm curious is this for homework or a project?  I just want to know why your doing this?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello again!    

Thanks alot for your help, this is simply some homework i put on myself, since i was allready done with my project.

Normally i would create 1 table with all 3 types of consumables in it, and just order them by TYPE in that table, but i kinda wanted to try a new approach, and the fact my teacher couldn't figure it out, well, it made me wanna figure it out more!

I failed though, and thought maybe someone else could figure it out, but i guess it was just to bad to fix.

I appreciate your reply, will get to work right now, thanks alot!

Comment: I think you could take the sql code above and do the 3 tables, but it might take a little more work and fine tuning.  I believe it is possible just not practical in the first place.  Glad it worked for you.